# iOS - How to know when NSOperationQueue finish processing a few operations?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, download, nsoperation

I need in my application to download directories and their content. So I decided to implement a NSOperationQueue and I subclassed NSOperation to implement NSURLRequest etc...

The problem is I add all the operations at once and I can't figure out when all the files for one directory are downloaded in order to update the UI and enable this specific directory.

Now I have to wait that all the files from all the directories are downloaded in order to update the UI.

I already implemented key-value observing for the operationCount of the NSOperationQueue and the isFinished of the NSOperation but I don't know when a directory has all the files in it !

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is more convenient to use dispatch_group_async. See this link [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632235/how-do-i-know-all-my-tasks-in-grand-central-dispatch-finished

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add a "Done" `NSOperation` which has all other `NSOperations` for one directory as dependency.

Something like this:

```
NSInvocationOperation *doneOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(done:) object:nil];

NSInvocationOperation *op1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) object:nil];
[queue addOperation:op1];
[doneOp addDependency:op1];

NSInvocationOperation *op2 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) object:nil];
[queue addOperation:op2];
[doneOp addDependency:op2];

NSInvocationOperation *op3 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) object:nil];
[queue addOperation:op3];
[doneOp addDependency:op3];

[queue addOperation:doneOp];
```

`doneOp` will only run after `op1`, `op2` and `op3` have finished executing.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my operations are concurrent. Is your example still ok ?

Comment: Of course, that's the whole point of dependencies. In a non-concurrent operation queue you would just add your operations in the correct order to achieve the same. But an operation will not run until all its dependencies have finished executing.

Comment: Kudos to you. That's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: It is better than KVO approach because it is safer and more straightforward.

Comment: Does it matter whether you add the dependency before/after adding the operation to the queue?

Answer (score 5):

```
[opQueue operationCount]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create some sort of Directory class with a properties such as loadedCount (initially 0) and fileCount (initialized to however many files are in the directory) and create a dictionary mapping each NSOperation to the appropriate Directory before adding the operation to the queue. Inside your callback for isFinished, you could pull the Directory object for the given NSOperation out of the dictionary and increment the directory.loadedCount by 1. If your directory.loadedCount == directory.fileCount, trigger an update to the UI.

Comment: That was my first idea. But I was wondering if that was the correct way to do it or if there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code to avoid enqueuing all requests at once. Enqueue only requests for a single directory at a time. When `operationCount` reaches zero, you can be sure that all the requests either completed or failed, update the UI and enqueue the requests for the next directory. Proceed until the array of directories is empty.

The advantages are:

- relative simplicity
- you don't have to query the file system only to figure out what has been downloaded
- if need be, you can re-enqueue failed requests without changing other logic.