# Asynchronous Twitter operations in an NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, nsoperationqueue, twrequest

To download a bunch of Twitter timelines, I created `TWRequest` objects in a loop and put them into an `NSOperationQueue`:

```
twitterRequestQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

// Get a reference to a Twitter account

NSArray *screenNames = @[@"gruber", @"kottke", @"ev", @"brad", @"borkware", @"jack", @"greatdismal", @"wilshipley"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];

for (NSString *screenName in screenNames) {
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"screen_name" : screenName, @"count" : @"200" };
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:parameters requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
    [request setAccount:account];

    // Make an operation using the Twitter request
    NSBlockOperation *twitterOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
            // Do stuff with the responseData
        }];
    }];

    // Put the requests into an operation queue
    [twitterRequestQueue addOperation:twitterOperation];
}
```

To determine when all timelines had been downloaded, I first tried [using KVO on `twitterRequestQueue`'s `operationCount`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049001/get-notification-when-nsoperationqueue-finishes-all-tasks). I also tried [adding a dependant operation to the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998532/ios-how-to-know-when-nsoperationqueue-finish-processing-a-few-operations?lq=1) after all the Twitter requests. Both these failed because the Twitter requests return almost immediately and get removed from the operation queue before their completion block gets called.

Instead, I stored my requests manually in a mutable array, calling a custom method `[self requestCompleted:request];` at the end of the Twitter completion block, and manually removing the request from my mutable array as each finished:

```
- (void)requestCompleted:(TWRequest *)request
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = [request parameters];
    NSString *screenName = [parameters valueForKey:@"screen_name"];
    NSLog(@"Request completed: %@", screenName);

    [requestsInProgress removeObject:request];
    if ([requestsInProgress count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"All requests finished");
    }
}
```

The other way I could make it work was to get the `signedURLRequest` from the Twitter request and download it synchronously using `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`.

Here's my question(s):

- Is there any point in using an `NSOperationQueue` to download Twitter requests like this?
- Is there a better technique to download multiple Twitter requests?
- Could I improve the way I use an operation queue for this?

Comment: I think you should rely on a concurrent operation since in non-concurrent operations, when the `main` terminates, the op is removed from the queue. If you want, I could try to provide some hints to you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SLRequest and blocks. What do you want to achieve?

See for example https://github.com/ArchieGoodwin/NWTwitterHelper