# Property, Threads, Memory management and Rock & Roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, memory-management

Environment: Mac OS X 10.9, Xcode 5.0.2, ARC disabled.

Question: How free memory of property after all thread finish job. See example below.

I`am create mini example with one button “(IBAction)btnRun:(id)sender”.
Example read txt file and fill NSArray property (sharedListWords). Then run two thread and each thread display words,
 see *OUT Section*. When threads finished a job, property (self.sharedListWords) not released! But I want free memory which allocated for (self.sharedListWords) property. The action “btnRun” exit before threads finished job and I cant release (self.sharedListWords) in this action.

**How free memory of property (self.sharedListWords) after threads finish job?** Yes good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998532/ios-how-to-know-when-nsoperationqueue-finish-processing-a-few-operations) by create dependency operation jobFinished(), **but how correct release property?**

And this is my first multithreading program on Objective-c, I will be glad for adjustments.

---

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    volatile int32_t sharedIndex;   // Shared between threads, current index in array
    NSOperationQueue* operationQueue;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
// Shared between threads, list of words
@property (atomic, retain) NSArray* sharedListWords;
- (void)worker;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction)btnRun:(id)sender
{
    // Read txt file dictionary of words, where is each words in new line.
    NSString* dictionaryFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/admin/dictionary.txt"];
    NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:dictionaryFilePath
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    // Get array of string separated by new line
    self.sharedListWords = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    //self.sharedListWords = @[@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five",@"six",@"seven",@"eight",@"nine",@"ten"];

    self->sharedIndex = -1;

    int numberOfThreads = 2;

    // Run method working() in separate threads
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfThreads; ++i)
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////////
        // Create a thread
        // Create new NSOperatin object with function puting in @selector() for run in other thread.
        NSOperation* startBruteOper = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(worker) object:nil];
        // Add the operation to the queue and let it to be executed.
        [operationQueue addOperation:startBruteOper];
        [startBruteOper release];
        /////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}

- (void)worker
{
    unsigned long countWords = [self.sharedListWords count];

    int32_t index = 0;

    // Use atomic operation for thread safe
    while( (index = OSAtomicIncrement32( &(self->sharedIndex) ) ) < countWords )
    {
        NSLog(@"[%@] working on \"%@\"",
              [NSThread currentThread],
              [self.sharedListWords objectAtIndex:index]);
    }

    NSLog(@"[%@] work is finish.", [NSThread currentThread]);
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Multithreading queue list
    operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
}

@end
```

*OUT Section*:

```
[<NSThread: num = 2}] working on "one"
[<NSThread: num = 3}] working on "two"
[<NSThread: num = 2}] working on "three"
[<NSThread: num = 3}] working on "four"
[<NSThread: num = 2}] working on "five"
[<NSThread: num = 3}] working on "six"
[<NSThread: num = 2}] working on "seven"
[<NSThread: num = 3}] working on "eight"
[<NSThread: num = 2}] working on "nine"
[<NSThread: num = 3}] working on "ten"
[<NSThread: num = 2}] work is finish.
[<NSThread: num = 3}] work is finish.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - How to know when NSOperationQueue finish processing a few operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998532/ios-how-to-know-when-nsoperationqueue-finish-processing-a-few-operations)

Comment: Martin R> and I can run [self.sharedListWords release]; in handler NSOperationQueue finish?

Comment: few minuts I`am testing )

Comment: Martin R> I`am make dependency handler jobFinished() see updated code, and first time it work fine, but when I press second time button it return segmantation fault on property self.sharedListWords. Maybe property need differently released?

Comment: I am so used to ARC that I almost cannot remember the MRC times anymore :-) But I think you should assign `self.sharedListWords = nil` in `jobFinished`, instead of calling `release`.

Comment: Yes self.sharedListWords = nil; work perfect. I`am have identical memory use before press button and after finished gob. Thank you very much Martin.

Comment: I have added my comments as an answer. - I think you should not edit your code in the question to the working code, because that makes the comments/answers unintellegible for future readers. The *question* should state the problem and an *answer* the solution.

Comment: Martin R> I`am issued corrected code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another operation which is *dependent* on all "worker" operations, as
described in

- [iOS - How to know when NSOperationQueue finish processing a few operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998532/ios-how-to-know-when-nsoperationqueue-finish-processing-a-few-operations)

That operation is run after all its dependencies have finished, so you can call

```
self.sharedListWords = nil;
```

in the finished operation to release the array.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct code, after Martins instructions.

AppDelegate.h:

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

    @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
    {
        volatile int32_t sharedIndex;   // Shared between threads, current index in array
        NSOperationQueue* operationQueue;
    }
    @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
    // Shared between threads, list of words
    @property (atomic, retain) NSArray* sharedListWords;
    - (void)worker;

    @end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (IBAction)btnRun:(id)sender
    {
        // Read txt file dictionary of words, where is each words in new line.
        NSString* dictionaryFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/admin/dictionary.txt"];
        NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:dictionaryFilePath
                                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        // Get array of string separated by new line
        self.sharedListWords = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                    [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

        //self.sharedListWords = @[@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five",@"six",@"seven",@"eight",@"nine",@"ten"];

        self->sharedIndex = -1;

        int numberOfThreads = 2;

        NSOperation* jobFinishedOper = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(jobFinished) object:nil];

        // Run method working() in separate threads
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfThreads; ++i)
        {
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // Create a thread
            // Create new NSOperatin object with function puting in @selector() for run in other thread.
            NSOperation* startBruteOper = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(worker) object:nil];
            // Add the operation to the queue and let it to be executed.
            [operationQueue addOperation:startBruteOper];
            [jobFinishedOper addDependency:startBruteOper]; // 'jobFinishedOper' run only when 'startBruteOper' finished!
            [startBruteOper release];
            /////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        // 'jobFinishedOper' run only when all prevous operation is finished!
        [operationQueue addOperation:jobFinishedOper];
        [jobFinishedOper release];
    }

    - (void)worker
    {
        unsigned long countWords = [self.sharedListWords count];

        int32_t index = 0;

        // Use atomic operation for thread safe
        while( (index = OSAtomicIncrement32( &(self->sharedIndex) ) ) < countWords )
        {
            NSLog(@"[%@] working on \"%@\"",
                  [NSThread currentThread],
                  [self.sharedListWords objectAtIndex:index]);
        }

        NSLog(@"[%@] work is finish.", [NSThread currentThread]);
    }

    - (void)jobFinished
    {
        self.sharedListWords = nil;
    }

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Multithreading queue list
        operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }

    @end
```