# Notifications when NSOperation finishes?

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation

Other questions and answers on Stack Overflow speak of observing the `operations.count`, adding a "Done Operation" 
etc.

[GCD finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632235/how-do-i-know-all-my-tasks-in-grand-central-dispatch-finished)[How do I know all my tasks in Grand Central Dispatch finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632235/how-do-i-know-all-my-tasks-in-grand-central-dispatch-finished)

[NSOperationQueue finishes operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998532/ios-how-to-know-when-nsoperationqueue-finish-processing-a-few-operations)

[KVO for monitoring all tasks finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049001/get-notification-when-nsoperationqueue-finishes-all-tasks)

Are there notifications I can subscribe to that send the operation which was finished?

Comment: Do you want to know when an operation finishes or when the entire operation queue finishes?

Comment: Okay, no problem! There are two usual ways, and I've provided both in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is simply to have your NSOperation's `main` post an NSNotification at the end of itself. Thus, anyone else can register for that notification and learn that the operation is over (and can come back to the NSOperation to pick up any data stored in properties that may be needed).

Here's a typical structure:

```
- (void) main {
    if ([self isCancelled])
        return;
    // ... all the action goes here ...
    if (![self isCancelled])
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
         postNotificationName:@"OperationFinished" object:self];
}
```

Note that you should *make no assumptions* about what thread the NSNotification arrives on.

The alternative is to use KVO on the NSOperation's `isFinished`, but this can get hairy and I'm not sure I would advise it.

Comment: Ah, so you're using a custom NSOperation class?

Comment: Yes, but that's not really important. If you are doing an NSBlockOperation you would just have to use the KVO solution, though.